# Find jar in an executable

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to transform my java code to an executable, however, this java code makes use of another jar that I wrote. This second jar can be found easily when I run the application locally (in IDE) but not when I create an exe out of it, then I can no longer find the embedded jar that I added.

In my IDE I use the following to currently find the right jar

```
String path = FXMLDocumentController.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

Then I drop the last part and replace it with `lib\AllInOneJar.jar`

I have been searching online as to how I would find a jar in an exe and it directs me to use the following

```
URL in = this.getClass().getResource("/AllInOneJar.jar");
```

or

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("lib/AllInOneJar.jar");
```

I'm still unsure as to how this would help me in finding the location of my jar within the exe I created.

Comment: Are you sure that the final jar, when extracted, has your secondary jar within it? If not, then make sure that while packing your jar, you include its dependencies as well.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that it has the jar within the exe. I also use other libraries as jars and it is able to use those. I just need the file path of this specific jar such that I can run it separately in my exe

Comment: How are you using this other JAR file? Library? Service provider? Forked process? Something else?

Comment: The jar that i'm trying to find is used to execute on the cmd